# Return matching type from tagged union type interface

Tags: typescript

It is known that you can simply use tagged union types to have correct types after querying them:

```js
export interface A {
    type: 'a'
    foo: string
}

export interface B {
    type: 'b'
    bar: string
}

export type U = A | B

const a: U = {}

switch (a.type) {
    case 'a':
        // is now A
        console.log(a.foo) // .foo is a string
        break
}
```

However, I can't manage to find a solution to dynamically get the correct type when dynamically finding it:

```js
export interface A {
    type: 'a'
    foo: string
}

export interface B {
    type: 'b'
    bar: string
}

export type U = A | B

class Foo {
    private items: U[]

    public get(name: U['type']) {
        return this.items.find((i) => i.type === name)
    }
}

const foo = new Foo()

const a = foo.get('a')
a // a is U but should be A
```

It seems that typescript can't automatically figure out the type.

I also tried using a generic type which I hoped typescript could guess, like that:

```js
public get<T extends U>(name: T['type']): T {
    return this.items.find((i) => i.type === name)
}
```

I hoped that T would be the interface which was selected by T['type'], but it had the same result, though.

Comment: We could write this by passing a typeguard to `find`, but the issue is that we cannot enumerate the constituents of the union without mentioning each one in that predicate. Note the shorthand inline typeguard syntax is `(x): x is T => expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately typescript won't do a "backward" inference like the one you describe (eg, we can't go from the field of some type to that type automatically). Instead, one solution is to explicitly describe your relationship. Then it's easy to get the behaviour you're looking for:

```
type UMap = {
    "a": A;
    "b": B;
}

class Foo {
    private items: U[]

    public get<K extends keyof UMap>(name: K): UMap[K] {
        return this.items.find((i) => i.type === name)
    }
}

const a = foo.get('a') // a has type A
const b = foo.get('b') // b has type B
```

I would also recommend generating the type `U` from the map instead of declaring it explicitly:

```
type U = UMap[keyof UMap]; // A | B
```

This gives you the benefit of only needing to update things in one spot when adding more types to the union.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have to use UMap _and_ the type in A & B, but I'm okay with that.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little unfortunate. However, [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) was just merged, and if/when it gets into the next release (TS 2.8) you can get this behavior without the `UMap`.

Comment: That would only work for 2 Interfaces, though. I plan to add more interfaces.